# How to integrate Zend framework 2 and Mongodb with shanty mongo library,

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework2

I downloaded Zend framework 2 beta3 Skeleton trying to integrate with Mongodb using Shanty mongo.can anyone please provide the steps..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should take look at [Doctrine MongoDB ODM](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm) instead. And ZF2 [module](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule) for it

Comment: Still I recommend you try this integration, it is of high quality, maintained by high skilled community and already integrated with ZF2. As well you can expect more zf2 modules to appear later with MongoDB ODM support.

Comment: Note: that module currently does not work out of the box with ZF2 beta 4.

Comment: @user1410753: If you'd rather not use the ODM, you can use [doctrine-mongodb](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb) on its own for some thin abstraction and utility atop the PECL driver. It should integrate well with Zend's DI container.